# C#, NullReferenceException is not catched

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, nullreferenceexception

Good afternoon. I cannot understand, why the block "catch" is not invoked, instead of it the programme stops working with NullReferenceException.

```
            string? nullable_string_1 = null;
            try
            {
                string non_nullable_string_1 = (string)nullable_string_1;
                System.Console.WriteLine(non_nullable_string_1.Length);
            }
            catch (System.NullReferenceException nullReferenceException)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine($"There is an invalid operation exception with message: \"{nullReferenceException.Message}\"");
            }
```

Comment: The code in your question **will** catch the NullReferenceException (with `non_nullable_string_1.Length` being the only candidate for causing a NRE here). There's no two ways about it. Whatever problem you have that led you to ask this question is not in the code you presented in your question.

Comment: I have run this code and it does catch the exception.

Comment: When I run your code it works OK for me.
If you are running in Visual Studio then by default the debugger will catch the exception first, if you close that window & continue the code continues to the catch block.

Comment: Thank you. But why did you spoil my reputation?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string? nullableString = null;
        try
        {
            string nonNullableString = (string)nullableString;
            Console.WriteLine(nonNullableString.Length);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException nullReferenceException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"There is an invalid operation exception with message: \"{nullReferenceException.Message}\"");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("After Exception Code Run");
    }
}
```

Output - It's Working
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Qum.png